# select particular input field name of particular form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

i have some html code like this

```
<form name="first"><input name="firstText" type="text" value="General" /> 
<input name="secondText" type="text" value="General" /> 
<input name="ThirdText" type="text" value="General" /> 
<input name="FourthText" type="text" value="General" /> 
<input name="FifthText" type="text" value="General" />
</form>

<form name="second"><input name="firstText" type="text" value="General" /> 
<input name="secondText" type="text" value="General" /> 
<input name="ThirdText" type="text" value="General" /> 
<input name="FourthText" type="text" value="General" /> 
<input name="FifthText" type="text" value="General" />
</form>
```

i want to select "secondText" of form "second" using jquery or javascript and i want to change value of it using jquery.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using jQuery:

```js
var element = $("form[name='second'] input[name='secondText']");
```

Using vanilla JS:

```js
var element = document.querySelector("form[name='second'] input[name='secondText']");
```

Changing the value: `element.val(value)` or `element.value = value`, depending of what you are using.

Answer (score 4):

To the point with pure JS:

```
document.querySelector('form[name=particular-form] input[name=particular-input]')
```

**Update:**

This selector will return the input named "particular-input" inside form named "particular-form" if exists, otherwise returns null.

The selector filter "form[name=particular-form]" will look for all forms with name equals "particular-form":
`<form name="particular-form">`

The selector filter "input[name=particular-input]" will look for all input elements with name equals "particular-input":
`<input name="particular-input">`

Combining both filters with a white space, I mean:

`"form[name=particular-name] input[name=particular-input]"`

We are asking for `querySelector()`: Hey, find all inputs with name equals "particular-input" **nested** in all forms with name equals "particular-form".

Consider:

```html
<form name="particular-form">
  <input name="generic-input">
  <input name="particular-input">
</form>
<form name="another-form">
  <input name="particular-input">
</form>
<script>
  document.querySelector('form[name=particular-form] input[name=particular-input]').style.background = "#f00"
</script>
```

This code will change the background color only of the second input, no matter the third input have same name. It is because we are selecting only inputs named "particular-input" nested in form named "particular form"

I hope it's more clear now.

;)

By the way, unfortunately I didn't found good/simple documentation about querySelector filters, if you know any reference, please post here.

Comment: Please explain what your answer is doing.

Answer (score 2):

```
// Define the target element
elem = jQuery( 'form[name="second"] input[name="secondText"]' );

// Set the new value
elem.val( 'test' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

**jQuery**

```
$("form[name='second'] input[name='secondText']").val("yourNewValue");
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/YLgcC/

Or:

**Native Javascript**

Old browsers:

```
var myInput = [];
myInput = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

for (var i = 0; i < myInput.length; i++) {
    if (myInput[i].parentNode.name === "second" &&
       myInput[i].name === "secondText") {
        myInput[i].value = "yourNewValue";
    }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/YLgcC/1/

New browsers:

```
document.querySelector("form[name='second'] input[name='secondText']").value = "yourNewValue";
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/YLgcC/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("form[name='second'] input[name='secondText']").val("ENTER-YOUR-VALUE");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this line too:

```
$('input[name="elements[174ec04d-a9e1-406a-8b17-36fadf79afdf][0][value]"').mask("999.999.999-99",{placeholder:" "});
```

Answer (score -1):

Add button in both forms. On Button `click` find nearest form using `closest()` function of jquery. then using `find()`(jquery function) get all input values. `closest()` goes in upward direction in dom tree for search and `find()` goes in downward direction in dom tree for search. [Read here](https://coderwall.com/p/wxjljq/jquery-find-and-closest-are-your-best-friends)

Another way is to use `sibling()` (jquery function). On button `click` get sibling input field values.